# Returning text input from kivy widget

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

How can I return the text I have written inside a Kivy TextInput Widget?
The widget is created inside the python code, and should start with a starting text which can be edited.

For some reason I can only get the starting text back from the input

```
    def read(self):
        with open(f"./drafts/draft.txt", "r+") as file:
                text = file.read()
                return text


    def view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        print(type(self))
        self.box = TextInput(text = self.read(),size_hint= (.6, .56), pos_hint= {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.51})
        self.add_widget(self.box)


        send_button = Button(size_hint_y = (.05), size_hint_x = (.44), pos_hint= {"center_y":.18, "center_x":.5})
        fun = partial(self.SaveOrder2, order = self.box.text)
        send_button.bind(on_relase = fun)
        self.add_widget(send_button)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need self.read()in text input rather you could do like this

```
self.box=TextInput(id='input1')
```

Then inside the send button

```
self.ids.input1.text
```

Where you want to return the text and that should do the work